# $.getJSON syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a $.getJSON call that populates a collection by making a Web API call :

```
$.getJSON("/api/rating", self.ratings);
```

How would I rewrite this if I want to add some of the options found in $.ajax such as beforeSend, data, success etc?

EDIT : I have tried both of these and none of the alerts are hit :

```
  $.getJSON("/api/rating")
                .beforeSend(function (xhr) {
                    alert("before");
                    $('#divLoading').addClass('ajaxRefresh');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Client', 'jQuery');
                })
                .success(function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    self.ratings = result;
                })
                .complete(function (result) {
                    alert("complete");
                    $('#divLoading').removeClass('ajaxRefresh');;
                })
              .error(function () {
                  alert("error");
              });

$.getJSON("/api/rating", self.ratings)
            .beforeSend(function (xhr) {
                alert("before");
                $('#divLoading').addClass('ajaxRefresh');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Client', 'jQuery');
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                alert(result);
                self.ratings = result;
            })
            .complete(function (result) {
                alert("complete");
                $('#divLoading').removeClass('ajaxRefresh');;
            })
          .error(function () {
              alert("error");
          });
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812585/beforesend-in-getjson

Comment: you can't use $.getJSON if you want to use beforeSend et al because .getJSON is only a short hand function which calls into the $.ajax function. Hence, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.getJSON is a shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

So your sample could translate into:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/api/rating",
  data: self.ratings,
  beforeSend: beforeSend,
  success: function (json) {
      // handle json
  }
});
```

etc.

Comment: So where would self.ratings go here?

Comment: @user517406 What is `self.ratings`? at this point it could be data, or it could be a success handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON(<url>,<data>,<callback>)
 .success(function() {

  })
  .error(function () {
  });
```

**EDIT:**

`.success()` and `.error()` has been deprecated and thus `.done()` and `.fail()` should be used instead.

Comment: .success and .error are depreciated in favor of .done and .fail