# How can I set beforeSend Listener on $.getJSON

Tags: jquery

I am using $.getJSON to get cross-domain ajax request. I want to add a loading effect on it.
Beside using

```
// Loading show    
$.getJSON("url", function(){ //Loading hide });
```

and

```
$.ajax({...})
```

How cant I bind before send listener on $.getJSON?
thank you!

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812585/beforesend-in-getjson

Comment: I mean I am finding other method beside those two =="

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `.ajaxSend()` listener. It will populate a global event listener for every Ajax call - like your getJSON. Reference here http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
    showSpinner();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    hideSpinner();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply show your loading graphic before calling `$.getJSON` and hide your loading graphic in the complete function.

```
ShowLoading();

$.getJSON({
   ...
   success: getJSONSuccess
});

function getJSONSuccess(response) {
   // handle response
   HideLoading();
}
```